# Google sheets not showing correct dates after reformatting

Tags: google-sheets, utc

I am trying to batch convert 5000 date values from this format:
11720
into a UTC compliant form of 2020-1-17 (for example).
However, when I use the drop down menus on sheets to perform this, the resulting date is 5/11/1932.
Any suggestions on what is going wrong? I would rather not have to change these all by hand....

Comment: What you're trying to convert is actually a string that you've made to represent a date, not a date value. What you're getting now is correct given the integer value 11720, which represents the date May 11, 1932. You're going to have to parse the strings into the proper format. It would most likely be easiest to do with VBA, but you're going to have to figure out how to tell if 11720 means Jan 17, 2020 or Nov 7, 2020 in VBA.

Comment: @ken white
I assume I can do the same in JS, since I am using sheets. Any idea on how to tell the parser to differentiate those two dates?

Comment: Not without some sort of context around it that will allow you to tell the difference. Otherwise, you're out of luck. There's no way that you can tell the difference or the desired result in code without more information. It's one of the many, many reasons that date values should be stored uniformly using the specific CCYYMMDD format, which is unambiguous - you always know that CC is the century, YY is the year, MM is the two digit month, and DD is the two digits for the day, and conversion to any other format for display is straightforward.

Comment: we are currently in the 21st century, so actually the standard is YYYYMMDD (or YYYY-MM-DD) as per ISO 8601.

Comment: 11120 is 11/1/2020 or 1/11/2020 ? how do you deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

if the MONTH can either be 1 or 2 digits (because of deletion of leading 0), and the DAY is always two digits (so day 9 is given as 09), and the year is always 2 digits and where the dates are NOT before the 1st/Jan/2000, and where the first date you want to convert is in cell A2, then you can use formula like this:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)=5,DATE(2000+RIGHT(A2,2),LEFT(A2,1),MID(A2,2,2)),DATE(2000+RIGHT(A2,2),LEFT(A2,2),MID(A2,3,2)))
```

then change the Format style suit your needs.